# Insert a row within another row while updating sql

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE `users` SET `D1`='hello ['firstname']' WHERE id_user >= 3
```

I want to update the D1 column with "hello ['firstname']"

I want to fetch firstname from another column with same row number. and the above syntax is not working out. I'm new to ṭhis. Is this possible? or not?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CONCAT for that purpose, and you can so combine strings together

```
UPDATE `users` SET `D1`= CONCAT('hello [',`firstname`,']') WHERE id_user >= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to construct a string with `firstname` -- the column -- in it?

If so:

```
UPDATE users
    SET D1 = CONCAT('hello', firstname')
    WHERE id_user >= 3;
```